# Access Gravity forms with javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to access gravity forms entries by JavaScript so I can make calculation in a specific field.
Let's say I have: username, email, phone number, quantity.
how can I access quantity field and make calculation on this field?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+gravity+forms+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.